# Do I need to remove event listeners when changing the object I'm listening to?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got some "pass-through" properties in my WPF ViewModels that use PropertyChange events to, for example, update dependent properties (a `Fullname = FirstName + SecondName` for example).

Previously, I've just done this:

```
    public KPIViewModel KPIViewModel
    {
        get { return kpiViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (kpiViewModel != value)
            {
                kpiViewModel = value;
                if (kpiViewModel != null)
                {
                    kpiViewModel.PropertyChanged += KpiViewModel_PropertyChanged;
                }
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => KPIViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, presumably the KpiViewModel_PropertyChanged hangs arround if I change the KPIViewModel object? Should I be doing this:

```
    public KPIViewModel KPIViewModel
    {
        get { return kpiViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (kpiViewModel != value)
            {
                if (kpiViewModel != null)
                {
                    kpiViewModel.PropertyChanged -= KpiViewModel_PropertyChanged;
                }
                kpiViewModel = value;
                if (kpiViewModel != null)
                {
                    kpiViewModel.PropertyChanged += KpiViewModel_PropertyChanged;
                }
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => KPIViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
```

And removing the existing KpiViewModel_PropertyChanged before adding a new one to the new object?

**Edit:** In response to "You should put this in the setter of the property in the actual KPIViewModel class", If I understand it, you think I should do something like this:

Say, I have a pretty simple case, a boolean that represents whether the viewModel should be shown or not on the screen, I have a few different views that display it, maybe I also want to perform some other random action on it's update too, I'd end up with something like this:

```
    private bool show;
    public bool Show
    {
        get { return show; }
        set
        {
            if (show != value)
            {
                show = value;
                if (MySummaryPageViewModel != null)
                {
                    MySummaryPageViewModel.UpdateFilter();
                }
                if (MyPickedDialogViewModel != null)
                {
                    MyPickedDialogViewModel.UpdateFilter();
                }
                if (MyPerformSomeOtherRandomActionViewModel != null)
                {
                    MyPerformSomeOtherRandomActionViewModel.DoThatThing();
                }
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Show);
            }
        }
```

Surely that's not sensible. The KPI ViewModel shouldn't be concerning itself with all these other objects logic surely. For a start, seems like hell to maintain for me, and the KPI is going to have to keep references of all these things simply to notify them of property changes.

Isn't this exactly why the INotifyPropertyChange interface exists?

Comment: What's the lifetime of the old `KPIViewModel`?

Comment: In this case, I wouldn't expect it to be long as it's usually generated from persistent models for a view, and thrown away after use. But I do a similar thing with the Models in other situations.

Comment: How do you create properties `KPIViewModel`? If you create every time new instance of `KPIViewModel`, then the unsubscribing from  `PropertyChanged` event is useless cause you are using new instance of object.

Comment: In this case, at the moment the KPIViewModel is not created in the constructor but is always set once on creation. I couldn't say if that's always going to be the case, though it likely will be.

Comment: why do you need subscribing to `kpiViewModel.PropertyChanged`? Cause you can just call the necessary method(in your case event handler) without any sunscribing. Just write a necessary method into your **setter** of `KPIViewModel` property.

Comment: But then KPIViewModel would contain implementation and logic owned by this class, which is hardly desirable (it's a general class used by lots of others).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the cleanest way to achieve something similar is to not handle the kpiViewModel `PropertyChanged` event in the containing ViewModel. Why not handle the `PropertyChanged` in the `KPIViewModel` itself (as you would normally expect). If `KPIViewModel` need to access members on the container ViewModel then just set a property on KPIViewModel that is the container ViewModel (**this** in your Property methods above)

Comment: This seems like an awful idea to me, I've tried to show how in an edit (code in comments is not nice).